# GNU Smalltalk: Problem with Example in Tutorial (Object creation)

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I tried to run the example of GNU Smalltalk in the documentation but ran into an issue.

```
Object subclass: Account [
  | balance |
  new [
    | r |
    r := super new.
    r init.
    ^r
  ]
  init [
    'initialize account' printNl.
    balance := 0
  ]
  get [
    ^balance
  ]
]
```

In the `new` method the `init` message is never sent to the `Account` method.
Heres my output:

```
st> Account new get
nil
st> Account new init get
'initialize account'
0
```

I took this example from the [GNU Smalltalk Documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual/gst.html#Creating-classes).

Can somebody help me spot the error?  I assumed that perhaps the `init` method of super is called, but `Object` does not have a `init` method.  Furthermore should `super` create a instance of the current class?

**Thanks Benjamin for the answer**

So my problem was that i did not distinguish between class functions (`new`) and Object functions

Fixed Code

```
Object subclass: Account [
  | balance |
  init [ balance := 0 ]
  get [ ^balance ]
]
Account class extend [
  new [ ^ (super new init) ]
]


st> Account new get
0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a slight change you've made to the code that means it won't work.

In Smalltalk, methods can be attached in one of two places: they can apply to *instances* of a class, which in this case would be account objects (like the one you get back from running `Account new`), or they can be *class* methods, which means they apply to the actual class itself, `Account`.

`Account init` is an instance method. It sets some sane defaults for the instance of the `Account` class you've made.  You wrote that correctly, and it's behaving as it should.

On the other hand, you've changed `Account new` from a class method to an instance method. When it's a class method, it replaces `Account`s existing `new` method with one that calls `init`. When it's an instance method, it doesn't really do anything, since you're not going to be calling `new` on the instance.

The fix is easy enough: tell GNU Smalltalk that the `new` method is a class method.  To do that, you just put the method on `Account class >> new` instead of loose in the `Account` class.

Comment: Is there any shorter syntax, ideally one without the class name, than `Account class >> new` for this?

Answer (score 2):

The first `new` should be `Account class >> new`. Thanks!

Comment: can you explain why this needs to be set? i'm confused that this works :D

Comment: because `new` is a method on the class-side, not on the instance.  You send `new` to the `Account` class, not to bank accounts.

Answer (score 1):

An other possibility is:

```
Object subclass: Account [
    | balance |
    Account class [
        new [
          ...
        ]

        otherClassMethod [
          ...
        ]
    ]

    instanceMethod [
      ...
    ]
]
```

Comment: i like the syntax. is there a convention on how to define Class methods?