# How to subclass OrderedCollection in GNU Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I'm reading a book using VisualWorks and I try to write the code in GNU Smalltalk. I have this:

```
OrderedCollection subclass: Stack [
    push: anObject [
         self addLast: anObject.
    ]

    pop [
        self isEmpty
           ifTrue: [^nil]
           ifFalse: [^self removeLast].
    ]
]

| st |
st := Stack new.
st push: 'a'.
Transcript show: st pop.
```

but it doesn't work. Can someone please explain me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working and how exactly?

Comment: I got Object: Stack error: should not be implemented in this class, use #basicNew instead. Stuart's response was what I needed. 

In the future I will try to be more specific and also add the messages i get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're getting `Object: Stack error: should not be implemented in this class, use #basicNew instead`?

If so, then it looks like you need to add `<shape: inherit>` in the body of your subclass.

See:

- [Basic Smalltalk Subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474268/basic-smalltalk-subclass)
- http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-smalltalk/2010-06/msg00080.html
- http://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual/html_node/Inside-Arrays.html

That seems like a bit of a leaky abstraction to me - but I guess it is what it is.

Comment: That was it <shape: #inherit>. 

Can you please explain to me what does this <shape: #symbol> exactly do? I don't quite understand from the documentation. Why don't we use it on all the classes we create by inheriting?

Comment: the <shape: > pragmas are a GNU Smalltalk specific thing, and I'm not very familiar with it. But I suspect it's just a design tradeoff - it will be providing special information to the compiler to tell it that it's a special type of class - and given that it's pretty rare that you want to subclass one of those types it was probably considered a reasonable tradeoff to simplify the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem is a design one. When learning smalltalk and object orientation, you will be happier if you choose composition rather than inheritance by default. A stack has a very limited interface

```
push: anElement
pop
isEmpty
```

so why not make a class `Stack` with an instance variable `stackData`

```
Stack>>initialize
    stackData := OrderedCollection new
```

An OrderedCollection has a very wide interface, and this way you get a Stack that only responds to a very narrow interface. That makes it much easier to understand and use.

Comment: I understand what you mean, and I've heard about: "Always favour composition over inheritance". This is my first oo language and with time, I guess I will sharpen my design skills. But the snippet above was just a simple/dummy example and it was never intended to be used in real applications.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code.
It's GNU-ST which does wierd things.

In other Smalltalks, this works like a charm.
Here is what I typed into a Smalltalk/X workspace, and it does the expected (shows 'a' on the Transcript):

```
OrderedCollection 
    subclass: #MyStack
    instanceVariableNames:''
    classVariableNames:''
    poolDictionaries:''.

MyStack compile:'
    push: anObject
         self addLast: anObject.
'.

MyStack compile:'
    pop
        self isEmpty
           ifTrue: [^nil]
           ifFalse: [^self removeLast].
'.

| st |

st := XStack new.
st push: 'a'.
Transcript show: st pop.
```